# Take a column of formula cells that return empty or a result, get only cells with a result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given a range of cells A1 to A1000 containing formulas returning either values or empty, I need to place formulas on cells B1 to B1000 so that B1 will contain the first value returned from a formula in A1:A1000, B2 will contain the second, and so on, until there are no values left to be returned.

This means the end result would be a simple list containing all values returned in the referenced range, in order and without any empty rows between one and another.

I thought of using the below formula to get the first cell that returned something, and then on the next formula checking against the previous result, but no dice, as it returns an error:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"; $A$1:$A$1000; 1; FALSE)
```

Comment: To do this with a formula it will need to be an array formula, that many array formulas will effect the calc times.

Comment: How about a macro that auto filters on the column to take out the blanks, then copies the remaining values, unfilters and pastes into the next column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid *array formulas* with a helper column:

In **C1** enter

```
=IF(A1="",0,1)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","",MAX($C$1:C1)+1)
```

and copy down.  Then in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Note that column **C** "marks" the rows containing values to be retrieved and column **B** retrieves the information.

Comment: Thanks, the other solution works just as fine, but this one is simpler to understand. Very clever logic there!

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/((ROW($1:$999)>1)*(A$1:A$999<>"")), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill down as necessary. If your data starts in row 1, then get rid of `(ROW($1:$999)>1)`.

[image: no_spaces]

Comment: This formula is a little bit difficult for me to understand, I'd love it if you could explain it, please!

Comment: Have you looked at the office.microsoft.com page for the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)? Have you tightened up the ranges to 4-6 rows and stepped through it with the [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) command? I am reluctant to rewrite the docs here. What part of the above two self-learning steps did not produce answers?

Comment: Yeah, its a pretty complex definition, although I will try understanding the workings of your formula.

Answer (score -1):

A formula isn't going to give you a good answer. If you just need a list of non-blank values, you might want to think about using the autofilter to just filter out blanks, or using a sort to put cells with values at the top. If you do need a distinct list, your best bet would probably be a short macro like this:

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()
    Const csS As String = "A"
    Const csT As String = "B"

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim lngLast As Long

    lngLast = Range(csS & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngSource = Range(csS & 1, csS & lngLast)
    Set rngTarget = Range(csT)
    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
            rngTarget.Value = rngCell.Value
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

The values for csS and csT can be changed to reflect your actual source and target columns.

Comment: I love vba scripts but I try my best to achieve my tasks using formulas, for the sake of simplicity. I'll keep this in the back of my mind anyways! Thanks!